# Download Font from Application to FontBook

Tags: font, font-book

Is it possible to download fonts from applications into FontBook? I go to the application and select "Show Contents" and find the `.otf` font files. I then try to download the font to FontBook and get a frightening warning message. 
[image: Font Warning]

Comment: Possible, yes. Always wise, no.

Comment: Any insights into what could be causing these "serious problems"?

Comment: Sorry, no - but you can usually Google for the full version of a font & get an unrestricted, licensed version quite easily